# How to improve quality of live streaming video in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I created Flash application that is broadcasting/watching live streaming with Adobe Media Server, and it's quality is low even with microphone turned off...
I set quality and bandwidth to 0, meaning that application has to decide which one is better to use in each moment.
It's much better than manually setting, since if I put lower quality and bandwidth it might have bad results with users with better broadcast( better upload ).

How does Skype and MSN handle theirs video talks?

Since it's the same upload/download used there, but quality is much better and video is synchronized with audio, which is not the case in Flash...

In Flash I am getting image frizzing, audio skipping...
And if for example DJ is broadcasting watchers won't be able to see/hear anything...

Is there a way to improve this?

Here is the camera configuration set before broadcasting:

```
camera.setQuality(0, 0); //bandwidth and quality set to auto
camera.setMode(595,415,15, true); //width, height, frame-rate, camera closest resolution
```

I haven't changed anything else, just attached this to streamer...

Is there something that should be changed/added?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on user connection, and camera quality, and it can't be changed.

For HD mode just change to:

```
camera.setMode(1280,720,30, true);
```

and back to normal set it with:

```
camera.setMode(595,415,15, true);
```

There is no need to reset netStream connection to change this, just run this code and camera will "restart" with this quality.

-Closed-